# Problems creating a cluster in ACS

Tags: azure, azure-container-service

I had this error on Saturday when creating an ACS cluster (DC/OS and DS2), I tried putting a different name but it seems that it had conflict with an existing storage account. Attendees of a talk I gave had similar problem(s) and their account was new, could someone provide info about what's needed to in order to avoid these type of problems? It seems that when it's creating the resources needed it's putting a duplicate ID, maybe it get's fixed by just adding as a prefix the cluster name?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can happen if same DNS name prefixes were used to create multiple ACS clusters. Fix would be to use different/unique master and agent DNS names for each ACS cluster.

I will take the feedback and work on updating the error message to be more actionable.

Comment: Thanks! I had that suspicion so I tried a different name but it didn't work. Does this uniqueness applies to my account only or is it global?

Comment: Uniqueness is global (DNS name needs to be globally unique).

Comment: Ok, noted! I hope that validation is included in the "validation phase" :) ... is there anything else that might cause problems when creating the cluster or just the name (besides the core limit depending of the orchestrator )